# Support vector regression for similarity prediction using libSVM

Tags: matlab, vector, regression, libsvm

I want to do support vector regression using LibSVM. I want the similarity score for faces. Now when I will train my faces, I will have shape face feataures as independent variable and score (any value between 0.1-1.0) as my dependent variable. a true positive face will train as 1.0. Otherwise portion of faces will be trained as score between 0.1-1.0 based on the quality of the training images. At the prediction stage, I want a score between 0-1.0 when the shape feature for a test image have been given. That means, we will have an one independent variable (feature vector) and one dependent variable (score between 0-1)dependent variable.

Comment: What is the question here? What have you tried?

Comment: Hi bjou, thanks for your attention. I just want to know that how can I formulate my training (more specifically, how can I put the score values in my training set). I know that for prediction, I can put any random value as my dependent variable. Also is " mean squared error" {2nd parameter of the output of svmpredict function) desired score that I want or something else

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/#weights_for_data_instances to apply instance weights.

In the LibSVM Matlab interface, the usage specification for `svmpredict` is:

```
[predicted_label, accuracy, decision_values/prob_estimates] = svmpredict(testing_label_vector, testing_instance_matrix [, 'libsvm_option']);
```

I believe the third return argument `decision_values/prob_estimates` is what you are looking for output scores.

Comment: I tested, but the first argument is giving me the desired answer. So, in this case, it is giving me a value between 0-1. Although the accuracy seems to be worse than classification. In classification, I am getting over 85% accuracy, but in regression, I am getting much worse accuracy. To be noted, I did not put any weight and did not optimize my parameter.